# How to get a Wayland session in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, 17.10, wayland

Ubuntu 17.04 comes with a wayland display server session. I've used and seen what it can do, I've used it before by selecting it from the lock screen just like selecting Unity 8 session, with a gear icon, that option doesn't appear in Kubuntu's lock screen. A blatant explanation would be that Kubuntu doesn't ship with wayland display server **but** it comes with an app exclusively called as wayland

[image: Screenshott]

The app itself does nothing that or I can't seem to understand how to use it and make wayland session possible

---

**Update**

I'm sure that I'm not running Wayland, but I've seen videos of KDE Neon running Wayland, is it just not possible in Kubuntu?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: For anyone reading this to date, you can now select wayland on the bottom left corner of your login screen

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since 5.4 it is possible to start a complete Plasma session on Wayland. For this go to a tty, log in, end the running X server (otherwise startup might block) and run the following command:

```
startplasmacompositor
```

Support for running a full Plasma session on Wayland is still in it's early stages. Bugs are to be expected and there are known missing features. Please consider it only as a mode to experiment with.

[Source KDE Community](https://community.kde.org/KWin/Wayland#Running_on_a_tty)

---

On Kubuntu you might need to Install `plasma-workspace-wayland`

```
sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
```

Comment: Ok, so CTRL+ALT+F1, login, sudo service sddm stop, startplasmacompositor. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

At least as of Kubuntu 17.10, you don't need to do much manual work. First make sure that Wayland integration is installed:

```
sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
```

Now you should have a session menu in the lower-left corner of the login screen (SDDM). Select "Plasma (Wayland)" there and you are done. Mind you, Wayland integration definitely isn't ideal at this point. But HiDPI support for example is way better.